Using Stokes' theorem for Archimedes' principle of buoyancy
I would like to use Archimedes Principle for an application example of Stokes Theorem, but I have some problems doing so... This is Stokes theorem:

Let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-manifold with boundary and $\omega\in\Omega_c^{n-1}(M)$ a differential $(n-1)$-form with compact support on $M$. Then \begin{equation*}
\int_{\partial M}\omega = \int_M\mathrm{d}\omega.
\end{equation*}

Now let's consider a Lifebuoy under the water, which is tied to the ground by a rope. Let $G$ denote the filled up torus that represents the lifebuoy. The water pressure at a point $(x,y,z)$ may be described by the function $\rho(x,y,z)=-z$ since the pressure gets higher if you go deeper in water. This is a very simple description, but that's okay. I guess we would need some constants and stuff, but let's just keep these out. I also have to mention that $\rho$ should not take positive $z$. Now to describe the force that the water puts on $\partial G$ at a point $p\in\partial G$ we need a normal vector $\hat{n}_p$ that points into the inside of $\partial G$. The force at that point then is $F(p):=\rho(p)\cdot\hat{n}_p$ wich is a function $F:\partial G\to\mathbb{R}^3$. The force thats acting on the whole surface of the torus then is the integral of $F$ over the whole surface $\partial G$.
Okay now here's the first question that appears for me because I don't really have experience here I guess. How exactly do you write this? I've read somewhere that one would write
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\partial G}F\,\mathrm{d}S.
\end{equation*}
But what does $\mathrm{d} S$ mean here...? Okay now this might not be the most important question I have about this. So let's move on.
The Principle now states that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\partial G}F\,\mathrm{d}S = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ \lambda_3(G)\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_3(G)$ is the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or we just write $\mathrm{vol}(G)$).
I have already a slight idea how to do this actually, but I can't really put everything together since there are some gaps. First, I should grab a chart $(U,\varphi)$ of $\partial G$, i.e. $\varphi:\partial G\supset U\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a diffeomorphism and $\varphi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^2\supset\varphi(U)\to U$ is then a local parametrization. Now I could apply some transformation theorem (...?) and get
\begin{equation*}
\int_{U}F\,\mathrm{d}S = \int_{\varphi(U)} (F\circ\varphi^{-1})(u,v)\cdot\sqrt{\det\left(\mathrm{d}\varphi^{-T}\mathrm{d}\varphi^{-1}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v,
\end{equation*}
where $\mathrm{d}\varphi^{-1}$ is the Jacobi-Matrix. Since $F(p)=\rho(p)\cdot\hat{n}_p$, I have to build the normal vector $\hat{n}_p$. This might be done by the cross-product of some basis vectors of the tangent space $T_p\partial G$. Here I am not sure how to do this in detail... But maybe let $u$ and $v$ be basis vectors for $T_p\partial G$ and
\begin{equation*}
\hat{n}_p=-\frac{u\times v}{|u\times v|}.
\end{equation*}
Then somehow I have to calculate that $\sqrt{\det\left(\mathrm{d}\varphi^{-T}\mathrm{d}\varphi^{-1}\right)} = |u\times v|$. Not sure how that would work... The integral then would just be
\begin{align*}
\int_{U}F\,\mathrm{d}S &= \int_{\varphi(U)} -\varphi^{-1}_3\cdot\left(-\frac{u\times v}{|u\times v|}\right)\cdot|u\times v|\,\mathrm{d}\lambda_2\\
&=\int_{\varphi(U)}\varphi^{-1}_3\cdot(u\times v)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda_2
\end{align*}
where $\varphi^{-1}_3$ is just the third component, which came from $\rho\circ\varphi^{-1},\,\rho(x,y,z)=-z$. And again I am not sure what I should write after the $\mathrm{d}$ here... for now I just said $\mathrm{d}\lambda_2$ but I don't know if that would be correct...
Now recall that
\begin{equation*}
u\times v =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            u_2v_3-u_3v_2 \\ u_3v_1-u_1v_3 \\ u_1v_2-u_2v_1
        \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
We could now integrate component wise:
\begin{align*}
        \left[\int_U F\,\mathrm{d} S\right]_1 & = \int_{\varphi(U)} \varphi^{-1}_3(u_2v_3-u_3v_2)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda_2,                          \\
                                      & = \int_{\varphi(U)} x_3\circ \varphi^{-1}\cdot(\mathrm{d} x_2\wedge \mathrm{d} x_3)(u,v)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda_2    \\
                                      & = \int_{\varphi(U)} ((\varphi^{-1})^*x_3\cdot\mathrm{d} x_2\wedge\mathrm{d} x_3)(e_1,e_2)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda_2     \\
                                      & = \int_{\varphi(U)} (\varphi^{-1})^*\underbrace{(x_3\cdot\mathrm{d} x_2\wedge\mathrm{d} x_3)}_{=:\omega_1} \\
                                      & = \int_{\varphi(U)} (\varphi^{-1})^*\omega_1\\& = \int_U\omega_1
    \end{align*}
For $i=2,3$ we gain $\omega_2 = x_3\,\mathrm{d}x_3\wedge \mathrm{d}x_1$ and $\omega_3=x_3\,\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2$. With stokes theorem we have
\begin{equation*}
\left[\int_{\partial G} F\,\mathrm{d} S\right]_i = \int_{\partial G} \omega_i\overset{\text{Stokes}}{=}\int_G \mathrm{d}\omega_i
\end{equation*}
for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ but we have $\mathrm{d}\omega_i = 0$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}\omega_3 = \mathrm{d}x_3\wedge\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2 = \mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge \mathrm{d}x_3
\end{equation*}
and therefore
\begin{equation*}
 \left[\int_{\partial G}F\,\mathrm{d} S\right]_3 = \int_G \mathrm{d} x_1\wedge \mathrm{d} x_2\wedge \mathrm{d} x_3 = \int_G 1\,\mathrm{d}\lambda_3 = \lambda_3(G).
\end{equation*}
Now here in the last part I am not really sure how to go from integrating over $U$ to $\partial G$... Do I really need a smooth partition of unity subordinate to some atlas of $\partial G$ here or can I just say $U=\partial G$...?
So there are quite some open questions for me to write it all down fully correct.. Maybe someone of you can help me here. Thank you very much!

Why are you messing with charts? Stokes’s Theorem is global, is it not?

You should also work out, once and for all, the formula that $F,dS = \vec F\cdot\vec n,dS = F_1,dy\wedge dz + F_2, dz\wedge dx + F_3,dx\wedge dy$. (You might some of my YouTube videos, linked in my profile, helpful for these things. Look around 3/4 the way down MATH 3510.)

@TedShifrin Thank you very much for your answer. I will look into it, thanks. That would make it a lot easier.

FYI - Archimedes did a lot of things, "Archimedes Principle" by itself is not clear. I was left wondering how the ability to join line segments of a fixed length together and be able to exceed the length of any other line segment (or in more modern language: for every real number there is an integer that is greater than it) would be useful with Stoke's theorem.

@PaulSinclair Oh, sorry. I will adjust the title
